# Diagram Designer for .NET

Tags: wpf, winforms, designer, diagram

You may know that .NET FCL does not have rich UI components out of the box.

I am looking for a free diagram designer framework for .NET, WinForms as well as WPF would be fine. A main feature I need is to display and edit tables with columns and relations between them with arrows. I think that Database Diagrams of MS Management Studio is a great example. If you know, how I could reuse that UI component in my custom application, please advise.

Nevertheless any advise, link will be appreciated.
Thank you.